# Grid loading performance issue when I change Page size=500 using Dev Express in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using dev express grid in MVC application, it works fine. But when I change page size=500 in pagination then grid view loading performance has been decreased.Can you suggest me how to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Perhaps you can show us your `ViewModel` and/or your ORM code in order for us to be able to give a more tailored answer

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance you can reduce the amount of data (per row) in your model if the bottleneck is the data transfer between the server and client. You can do this by creating a 'slimmed down' view model containing only essential data.

If however it's a database call that's taking a long time perhaps you need to look at your ORM code to understand what's taking so long.